# How to ask siri about event length in calendar?

Tags: ios, siri

How do I ask Siri about event length in calendar? She tells me that I have event and it starts at 10am but asking 'how long does it take' or 'how long is it' confuses Siri.

Comment: The event is shown with time duration and subject etc. on the screen. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @sdayal It does not show duration for me (at least for my 9h long event)

Comment: For me it shows the full calendar event with date, start end times, description, place etc. Are you on latest version of ios?

Comment: how do you ask siri about the calendar? @sdayal

Comment: Once siri is active, tap on ? symbol on bottom left of screen and select calendar. It then lists common ways to use calendar using siri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (I am on iOS 9.0.2), Siri cannot explicitly tell you the duration of the event. For events that are longer than three (3) hours, it also does not provide the end time of the event. Siri also (mostly) cannot do things related to previous items requested if you do not refer to it clearly, which is why "how long does it take" or "how long is it" will confuse Siri.

You can only work out the duration of the event if they are or shorter than 3 hours as Siri will only show you the start and end time. Past 3 hours, you have to physically enter your calendar app to find out.